# How to fish from a kayak?

Tags: fishing, kayaks

As a present I was recently given a Pelican Odyssey 100X. Before getting that I had fished using a neighbor's regular kayak.

Is fishing from the shore the same as fishing off of a kayak, and is kayak trolling a good way to fish?(Which lures are recommended for trolling?)

I would be fishing for bass/pickerel in a local pond.

Basically just trying to become a decent fisherman.

Comment: The Pelican Odyssey is a good fishing kayak. The only difference I know of is learning how to balance while standing (or how to properly cast over your shoulder while sitting), and remembering to bring everything you need. If you have a fish stringer, you can probably tie it off to one of the cleats, or you can use an ice chest as a live well.

Answer (score 4):

#### Expanding on my comment

Fishing from a kayak is not really that much different from fishing from any other watercraft. You have less space to work with, like fishing from a Personal Water Craft, but it's certainly doable.

If you plan to do a serious amount of fishing from your kayak, or plan to be out for very long, or plan to be in rough water, there are some great add-ons you can get for your boat.

[image]

(Via [South TX Kayak](http://www.southtexaskayak.com/kayak-fishing-attachments/))

But honestly, though, in most situations, all you really need is your kayak and your rod. You can use a stringer tied to a cleat on the boat to keep the fish you catch, or you can convert one of the storage compartments or even an ice chest to a live well by filling it with water. Other than that, just get out there and have fun.

[image]

(Via [South TX Kayak](http://www.southtexaskayak.com/kayak-fishing-attachments/))